# JavaEE @Injection / @EJB returns null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm new to JavaEE programming and I'm having difficulties with @Injection. To familiarize mysels with databases, I decided to create a simple CRUD application and followed this example: https://code.google.com/p/javaee6-crud-example/source/browse/ I created basically same files but somehow, I'm getting a null exception after @EJB.

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean
public class MainUcenci {
        private List<Ucenec> ucenci;

        @EJB
        private ServletDAO servletDao;


        @PostConstruct
        public void init(){
                ucenci = servletDao.getUcenci();
        }

        public List<Ucenec> getUcenci(){
                return ucenci;
        }

}
```

after testing I found out that when init() is called, servletDao is still null despite the fact that it should have been injected by then (isn't the whole point of init method that it's called after all injections?).

Here is also the relevant part of ServletDao code

```
@Stateless
public class ServletDAO {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("$objectdb/db/sola_ucenec.odb");
        EntityManager ucenecEm = emf.createEntityManager();

        public List<Ucenec> getUcenci() {

           List<Ucenec> ucenecList = null;

          ucenecList = ucenecEm.createQuery("SELECT g FROM Ucenec g",                   Ucenec.class).getResultList();

        return ucenecList;
        }

}
```

P.S. In JSF I call it like:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{mainUcenci.ucenci}" var="item">
```

Comment: Just to make sure; you're deploying that code to an application server, right?

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm using Tomcat 8.0.18.

Comment: This will not work with Tomcat. Tomcat is only a Servlet container that is by itself not capable of handling EJBs nor CDI. You should try TomEE http://tomitribe.com instead.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed seemed to be the problem.